# What Are These People Trying To Accomplish With This Scam?

Tags: partner

I am just finishing getting my LinkedIn put together and am also almost job ready. Toward the end I hired a freelancer to help guide me through some projects. He seemed nice and interested in showing me what he was doing with good commentary. Did not just throw up code to go with mine.

He recently offered me the same exact proposal as this individual who contacted me via LinkedIn:

> Hi Nonames,
>
> Do you know Toptal or Upwork.com?
>
> Both toptal and Upwork.com is a remote job site.
>
> I am writing to introduce you to a new position. If you have some
> experience in freelancing, you can easily understand what I want.
>
> I have been working at freelancing market for many years as a senior
> full-stack developer and had earned many funds($10000) per month.
>
> By the way, there are special jobs which only US freelancers can
> apply. Only US freelancers can apply and be hired for these jobs.
> Usually, these jobs' budget is really large, and the rate(hourly) is
> much higher than other normal jobs which any freelancer can apply.
>
> However, I am a non-US resident. So, I cannot apply for these great
> jobs. :(
>
> This is just a chance we can sync and cooperate. You are in the USA.
> Right? Yes
>
> The role in this cooperation(Only interview skill with the basic
> knowledge needed. No coding or development):
>
> You will register your application to several freelancing websites as
> a freelancer.
>
> We will get remote software projects from several freelancing
> websites, like toptal and Upwork
>
> In this case you need to have one free computer for sync short test
> coding and simple pair programming for some clients. ( this is from my
> experience)
>
> When we get an interview with the client, you might help me with your
> native English. (Essential part).
>
> • Do you know Anydesk or TeamViewer? Anydesk is a remote-control
> software, so We can work together with anydesk tool.
>
> • You should turn on your computer in your daytime so I can work on
> this.
>
> • If you have a free computer, that would be great.
>
> Then I will complete the jobs and get paid. This fund is ours.
>
> The payment for this position:
>
> You will get paid 25% of the income which I earn using your account.
>
> You will probably earn monthly extra revenue from me.
>
> If you are interested in this, let's discuss in more detail on
> telegram.
>
> **** is my telegram ID.
>
> Regards,
>
> Luis

The only difference is that my freelancer said he was banned for using the US Upwork site for some reason, he's from a another country, moved to US with his dad three years ago. He sends money to his sister who takes classes in China. We originally went through Freelancer then he said he'd rather use PayPal China site to avoid 10% fee and I aid fine as long as it is secure. Looking at this now it seems ridiculous but the guy gained my trust (although it did seem fishy). Thanks to Luis above I thought okay something is wrong. If someone could explain what is going on here I'd appreciate it.

Last, here is my freelancer's further explanation about his Upwork idea from Slack on 12/15. I love how much it looks like a template. He intros with explaining Upwork to me:

Me:

> Can you help me and make me a doc that explains what we are doing with
> Upwork and what Upwork is doing for us? I keep meaning to review and
> understand your proposal about the idea but have not.

Him:

> What is Upwork?
>
> Upwork is a platform that offers the opportunity for the clients and
> the developers to meet on certain projects.
>
> The clients post their projects to be done and then the developers bid
> on them.
>
> The former picks up the best candidate among applicants and sends the
> offer to him/her.
>
> 2. What we are doing on Upwork and Upwork is doing for us
>
> You have an Upwork account as both a freelancer and a client.
>
> You can bid on the projects as well as post your projects to hire
> someone.
>
> As you know, we should handle many projects on our hands in order to
> make more bundle.
>
> The more project we control the more profit we make.
>
> Upwork is one of the great platforms which can provide such an
> environment with us.
>
> In order to get projects, you should bid on the posted projects. As
> you know, your account is a new one so it may be difficult to get them
> at first.
>
> That’s why you should bid on some projects every day.
>
> But I think you are a perfectionist so you are less likely to bid on
> the projects which you are not confident with. It is not way how we
> can make more bundle.
>
> You can bid on any projects which share the same stacks (i.e., MERN)
> with you and me.
>
> Once you win a project, you don’t have to worry about its development.
> I can help you in all ways. Be sure that you can always know how the
> project will be going on.
>
> We can split into how much we will make in the ratio we agree on.
>
> Or whenever you are busy, I can bid on the project in person via your
> anydesk. What I suggest the idea for is that we should get projects
> there soon.

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's way to build "fake" reputation by completing your own jobs. That way it looks like one is well seasoned, has been very successful, and has made clients happy on the crowdsource site even though they *really* haven't.

It's also a way for banned/disallowed individuals to use the site *through* you... making *you* liable for any actions they take on the site.

It's a retake on the... "here, I have this check but no bank account. If you cash it for me, you can keep 10%." You cash it, give the person their 90%... and then the check bounces and you are out *all* the money.

**It's just a scam.. ignore it and move on.**

***Nothing*** beneficial to YOU will be found in their proposal.

Comment: can I contact you via chat please and ask a few more questions?

Comment: Sorry I don't really "chat" I don't have the time. Not sure what other questions you would have. **Nothing** anyone offers who suggest this type of arrangement is worthwhile. **Nothing** the tell you about how you'll "make money" or "get ahead" is true. They are merely lying to you in the hopes you'll fall for their scam. Just ignore these offers. Anyone proposing such an arrangement is merely looking to use and take advantage of your gullability.